# How to create and sign up and sign in form in JSwing using MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql, swing, actionlistener

I'm working with a simple sign up and sign in user interface system which is connected to a databse using MYSQL. I am experiencing problems in checking passwords in the sign up form and checking whether the username and passwords are matching in the sign in form. The console shows error with getting text from the password field as well as comparing the fields to ensure the details are correct or not

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // entry fields in sign in form JTextField and JPassword
    String u1 = tb1.getText();
    String p1 = pwd1.getText(); //password field
    //entry fields in sign up form JTextField and JPassword
    String u2 = tb2.getText();
    String p2 = pwd2.getText(); //password field
    String p3 = pwd3.getText(); // password field
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase", "root", "Luxan@22"
        );
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        if(e.getSource() == signup) {
            if(pwd2.equals(pwd3) == true) {    
                PreparedStatement sts = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO user(username, password) VALUES (?, ?)");
                sts.setString(1, u2);
                sts.setString(2, pwd2);
                sts.executeUpdate();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Passwords are not matching");
            }
        } else if(e.getSource() == signin) {
            PreparedStatement sts = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
            sts.setString(1, u1);
            sts.setString(2, p1);
            ResultSet result = sts.executeQuery();
            if( result.next()) {
                System.out.println("You are successfully logged in");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Incorrect username and password");
            }
        }
        con.close();

    }catch (Exception e){System.out.println(e);}

}
```

Comment: please show us the error message

Comment: *The console shows error with getting text from the password field* - sounds like you defined your variables as "local" variables. They should be defined as "instance" variables so they can be used by any method in the class.

Answer (score 0):

Since we have very little information on your GUI and how it is built and what errors you are getting, I will assume that your password fields are properly declared and accessible from other classes.

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you are trying to do, but I assume you want to match the password and username used in the login form vs the ones in your database inserted upon singning-up, and if they match, let the user in, correct?

So you should query your mySQL database and select the user matching tb1.getText() <--- I assume this is your username field, and get this password from the database and compare it to what's inside pwd1.getText().

You seem to be trying to get data input inside another form, the sign-up form with

```
    String u2 = tb2.getText();
    String p2 = pwd2.getText(); //password field
    String p3 = pwd3.getText(); // password field
```

Instead, I use something like this:

```
                try {
                        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                        String userName = "root";
                        String password = "";
                        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mytable";
                        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);

                        PreparedStatement ps = null;
                        String query = "SELECT  email, password from members WHERE email LIKE '%"
                                + txtUsername.getText() + "%'";
                        ps = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(query);
                        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                        if (rs.next()) {
                            String dbasePassword = rs.getString("password").toString();
                            String inputPassword = txtPassword.getText();

                            if (dbasePassword == inputPassword ) {
                                System.out.println("You are successfully logged in");

                            } else
                                //If user is found in the database but passwords do not match
                                System.out.println("Please verify username and password and try again.");

                        } else {
                            //If username isn't found in the database
                            System.out.println("You must be registered to use this software.");
                        }
                        ps.close();
                        connection.close();
                    } catch (SQLException se) {
                        se.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception evte) {
                        evte.printStackTrace();
                        } finally {
                        if (connection != null || ps != null) {
                            try {
                                connection.close();

                            } catch (Exception excc) {
                                Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, excc);
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
```

Now this might not be exact as I wrote it in notepad and can't doublecheck, but you get the idea. You need to get the username and password row from your mySQL table, and compare it to what the user has input.

May I also suggest that you look into encryption, as it is not very secure to have unecrypted passwords inside a database, much less pull them over the wire. I personally have users sign-up on a website that handles encryption upon sign-up, and the password is hashed and salted before being inserted into the database (Something like BCrypt). When the user logs in my desktop app, the encrypted password is pulled from the database, and what the user types into the passwordfield is passed through an encryption class, and only then those two are compared to each other.

Also make sure to create a mySQL user with limited priviliges if you are going to put the log-in information inside your app, and use that one to SELECT and INSERT.

Now this might not be the most secure way, but what really is these days but I digress.

I believe the errors you are seeing are because the sign-up form is now empty. One way to debug would be to print the lines u1, p1, u2, p2 (Scrap that p3, which leads me to believe it is the confirmation of the password when signing-up and is useless right now). Print those lines before establishing connection and you'll see exactly what those strings contain.

Anyways, if you want further help, I suggest posting a bit of code WITH the logs or exceptions being thrown, this way you'll get better help much faster.

Hope this helps.